# Make a SWF have a transparent background?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

If I have a one SWF movie imported inside of another, how do I make the inner one have a transparent background?

Comment: -1 have you tried that before asking...? with just a few lines of code you'll notice that the loaded .swf have always a transparent background...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWFs imported will always have transparent background - the **Loader** object itself doesn't work like, say iFrame in HTML. Unless you have a background in the SWF made up of some graphics, or MovieClips, Sprites, Buttons... whatever else, then you won't see the default backdrop you can see in IDE while working with the FLA file of that SWF.

Answer (score 0):

try different [BlendModes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#blendMode)

Comment: actually, don't do that unless it's absolutely necessary, it'll be very expensive performance wise.