# How to Make Stage transparent in Action script 3 (Adobe flash professional)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, movieclip

I am Making a text animation in AS3, Which will then added in a movie clip. So i want a Transparent Stage. Is there any way to make **Stage Transparent**.
If possible then describe in detail.
Thanks in Advance>>

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148250/make-a-swf-have-a-transparent-background?

Answer (score 0):

To set the `wmode` parameter to `transparent`. Check your flash object's html code.

```
<object classid="00" width="600" height="450">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="wmode" value="direct" > // change this ...
```

to this:

```
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" >
```

Setting the bg colour of your flash file will be ignored if you set the wmode to transparent. If you run the *.swf* as inside the player externally the background color will be shown.